# numpy array of numpy arrays of float numbers becoming an 'object' instead of 'float'

Tags: python, numpy

I have huge list of arrays, each comprising of float64, with varying array lengths. I have appended them into one large numpy array - however the dtype of numpy array is an 'object' instead of float64. I understand this might be due to varying lengths, so I tried to pad the varying lengths with zeros and yet am unable to convert the master array to dtype float. Below is a reproducible instance of this happening:

```
import numpy as np

A = [1.0, 2.0]
B = [3.0]
C = [5.0,6.0]
conc = []
conc.append(np.array(A))
conc.append(np.array(B)) #If I skip appending B, I get conc.dtype = float64 
conc.append(np.array(C))
conc = np.array(conc)
print(conc.dtype)

for i in range(0, len(conc)):
  if len(conc[i]) < 2:
    conc[i] = np.append(conc[i], np.zeros(2 - len(conc[i]), dtype = float))
    print(conc[i].dtype)

print(conc, conc.dtype, conc.shape)
#conc = conc.astype(np.float64)
```

P.S: The original large array is already available to me as is and is actually an array of different sounds of different lengths (it is a audio classification problem). Hence, I am trying to find ways to append zeros at a later stage as opposed to appending at the time of creation of the array.

Comment: If you padded everything right, `np.stack(conc)` should make a new 2d array.  `astype` can't change the shape of `conc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to pre-allocate the array, which is possible because you know the size ahead of time:

```
lst = [A, B, C]
shape = (len(lst), len(max(lst, key=len)))
arr = np.zeros(shape)
for i, a in enumerate(lst):
    n = len(a)
    arr[i, :n] = a
```

If you want to take the approach of padding individual arrays first, you can do that too:

```
N = len(max(lst, key=len))
for i in range(len(lst)):
    n = len(lst[i])
    if n < N:
        lst[i] = np.concatenate((lst[i], np.zeros(N - n)))
arr = np.array(lst)
```

The key is that assigning to the elements of an object array or list will not change the type. You need to make a new array for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The start - a list of lists that vary in size (they could also be arrays):

```
In [625]: alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

Make an array - essentially the same thing, with references to the lists.  `object` dtype required, else we get a warning.

```
In [626]: arr = np.array(alist, object)
In [627]: alist
Out[627]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
In [628]: arr
Out[628]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5]), list([6])], dtype=object)
```

Can't concatenate them:

```
In [629]: np.stack(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-629-5e39aed5411e>", line 1, in <module>
    np.stack(arr)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in stack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 426, in stack
    raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Modify the lists to same size (actually I'm making new lists):

```
In [630]: arr[1]=[4,5,0]; arr[2]=[6,0,0]
In [631]: arr
Out[631]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([6, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
```

calling array on this doesn't change anything:

```
In [632]: np.array(arr)
Out[632]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([6, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
```

`astype` doesn't help either.  `astype` can't change the shape or put an array/sequence in a single element slot.

```
In [633]: arr.astype(int)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-633-486203c45b85>", line 1, in <module>
    arr.astype(int)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But I can apply `stack` to this:

```
In [634]: np.stack(arr)
Out[634]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```

another option is convert the array back to list, and then make the array from that:

```
In [635]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[635]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```

---

If I modified the lists in-place, I'd see the change in both `arr` and `alist`, because they contain the same references:

```
Out[637]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5]), list([6])], dtype=object)
In [638]: arr[1].append(0);arr[2].extend([0,0])
In [639]: arr
Out[639]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([6, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
In [640]: alist
Out[640]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 0], [6, 0, 0]]
```

This kind of in-place change isn't possible if the list/array contained arrays.  `np.append/concatenate` make a new array, with a lot of copying.